# LOGINDEXBUILD on DB2 HADR database

Tags: db2-luw

We have a HADR database and set LOGINDEXBUILD to ON, but when takeover takes place the standby marks the indexes invalid and indexes are being re-created and as the database is large it takes multiple hours to complete, the tables are partition by range and LOG INDEX BUILD table attribute is null. We use DB2 v11.1.4.4 on centos 7, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you verify that the standby database (before takeover) also had LOGINDEXBUILD database configuration parameter set to ON ?

Comment: Check the [The causes to mark index invalid, and how to recover the indexes](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6472817) note, especially if you had failed last offline reorg or one of INDEXREC setting mentioned there. You may check db2diag.log entries on standby to understand, when it happened exactly to correlate with the corresponding table actions on primary.

Comment: LOGINDEXBUILD on the stanby database is also ON and INDEXREC is SYSTEM (RESTART), we did not have offline reorg

Comment: Do you see any output on the former standby from the following command? `db2diag -g "message^=ADM5572I"`

Comment: No there is not any such messages

Comment: Open a support ticket with IBM, if you have a support contract.